# EditText afterTextChanged(Editable view) handler not getting necessary text value after text changed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

Been developing in android for a while, but this isn't something I've encountered. I have an EditText object on my view called adText, and I've successfully wired it to an event handler using the following snippet:

```
final EditText adPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textFieldAd);

adPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable view) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
        }
    });
```

Here's my problem: if I type a space(" ") character after letter any [A-Z][a-z] in the EditText field, I don't get back a view with text that includes the space that I typed.

So, for example, suppose I have the following text in my EditText field "723ab". If I put a breakpoint in afterTextChanged and type the following in the text field: " ", the text value in afterTextChanged will be "723ab". Furthermore, when I type " ", the cursor doesn't move forward. It's like there's some sort of text filter on the EditText field (which I've looked for, and no such filter exists).

Furthermore, If I have the following my EditText field "723", and I type " ", the cursor moves forward and my afterTextChanged listener picks up "723 " just as I'd expect it to. What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you post the xml file

Comment: What could be in the xml that would affect this? It really is just a minimal EditText object inside a basic LinearLayout. I'll post if more people request.

Comment: I don't know but maybe you missed something because this code looks good I can't find a problem in it

Comment: Yeah, I'm really curious If I'm missing some sort of filter in the code somewhere, but I made absolutely sure that there are no InputFilter objects being applied to this EditText field.

Comment: do you have an input type set for the edit text?  if it's for a numeric input, it won't allow spaces, for example.

Answer (score 0):

So, the seed of the problem ended up being this: if a space AFTER a letter is typed into the EditText, and only then, afterTextChanged will get called TWICE. The first time will not include the updated string with the space at the end, but the second time will include it. I'm super curious if anyone knows why Android chose to implement this feature for the text changed event.